# Comma between author and pagenumber

Tags: citing, natbib, punctuation

I need help with my term paper. When I quote with `\cite[px]{author}`, I want to remove the comma between the author and the pagenumber (px).

I get this: (author, px)

I need this: (author px)

Thank you!

Here's the file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{geometry}                % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options.     There are lots.

\geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=35mm, right=35mm, bottom=25mm}                 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{underlin}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@cite[2]{
({ #1\ifthenelse{\boolean{@tempswa}}{ \nolinebreak[3] #2}{}})
}
\makeatother



\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}


\newpage                                        % Activate to display a given date or no date

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\attrib}[1]{\nopagebreak{\raggedleft\footnotesize #1\par}}                  
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage    
\section{Introduction}
As a young author "who was yet to find a public he was cautious about immediately   identifying himself with a work hat he himself regarded as shocking"
\cite[x]{Ziff}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.50}\normalsize

\newpage
\begin{thebibliography}{------}

\bibitem[Ziff]{Ziff}
Ziff, Larzer. "Introduction" \textit{Maggie: A Girl of the Streets and Other Tales of New York.} Stephen Crane. London: Penguin Books, 2000. vii-xxv. 
\end{document}
```

Okay, here I added all the usepackages and the part of the bibliography that is relevant for the example I gave you above in the section. The output is a comma between the author Ziff and the pagenumber x. I would like to remove the comma so that the new output is (Ziff x) and not (Ziff, x). I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Since you are using `natbib`, simply add this to the preamble of your document (somewhere after `\usepackage{natbib}` and before `\begin{document}`):

```
\setcitestyle{notesep={  }}
```